# Google Vision wrong image orientation

Tags: react-native, image-processing, google-vision, vision-api

I'm making a object detection app with React Native and Google Vision api. My app working very well when I send horizontal image. But if I send high resolution vertical image, api find objects like that image is horizontal. Also api work correctly if I send low resolotion vertical image.

[image]

The resolution of the first image is 6936x9248 (actually it's appears as 9248x6936 in Samsung gallery, I don't know why)
and the resolution of the second image is 750x1000 (it's 750x1000 in gallery too).

Here the response of the Vision for both images.

For the first image:  `[{"mid":"/j/5qg9b8","name":"Packaged goods","score":0.5010282,"boundingPoly":{"normalizedVertices":[{"x":0.23222321,"y":0.45171654},{"x":0.7493964,"y":0.45171654},{"x":0.7493964,"y":0.5577906},{"x":0.23222321,"y":0.5577906}]}}]`

For the secon image: `[{"mid":"/j/5qg9b8","name":"Packaged goods","score":0.6785547,"boundingPoly":{"normalizedVertices":[{"x":0.43387607,"y":0.23372115},{"x":0.5493168,"y":0.23372115},{"x":0.5493168,"y":0.75314826},{"x":0.43387607,"y":0.75314826}]}},{"mid":"/m/01g317","name":"Person","score":0.53238875,"boundingPoly":{"normalizedVertices":[{"x":0.16410054,"y":0.65503424},{"x":0.6280196,"y":0.65503424},{"x":0.6280196,"y":0.9973958},{"x":0.16410054,"y":0.9973958}]}}]`

As you can see the results are different. At least the position of the lightsaber had to be the same. I don't know why, there is an image orientation issue.

It's my request that I send to the Vision api:

```
await fetch(config.googleCloud.api + config.googleCloud.apiKey, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "requests": [
                    {
                        "image": {
                            "content": base64 of the image,
                        },
                        features: [
                            { type: "OBJECT_LOCALIZATION", maxResults: 15 },
                        ],
                    }
                ]
            })
        });
```

Is the problem at my request?